# How to get a value after the first comma in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I want to get `Tex` out of this string.

```
ID  string
1   CN=username,OU=Tex,OU=Users,OU=Region1,DC=company,DC=com

substring(string, charindex(',', string) + 4, LEN(string))
```

I'm able to get to the first comma and get to Tex but how do I remove the rest of the string?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I ended up using. Thank you for all the answers!

```
LEFT(SUBSTRING(string, CHARINDEX('ou=', string) + 3, LEN(string)), 3)
```

Answer (score 1):

Another option is via a little XML

```
Select ID
      ,SomeValue = Cast('<x>' + replace(string,',','</x><x>')+'</x>' as xml).value('/x[2]','varchar(max)')
 From YourTable
```

**Returns**

```
ID  SomeValue
1   OU=Tex
```

Answer (score 0):

String functions in SQL Server are rather limited.  Here is one method:

```
select left(v2.str, charindex(',', v2.str) - 1)
from t cross apply
     (values (stuff(t.str, 1, charindex(',', t.str), ''))) v1(str) cross apply
     (values (stuff(v1.str, 1, charindex('=', v1.str), ''))) v2(str);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're always going to be looking for the first value after the first OU you can do this. But if you're going to be looking at values from the other OUs I'd use one of the options above as the syntax around this could get real messy real quick.

```
declare @SearchExpression varchar(max) = 'CN=username,OU=Tex,OU=Users,OU=Region1,DC=company,DC=com'

select Substring(
@SearchExpression,
charindex(',', @SearchExpression) + 4,  --+4 is the lengh of first ,=OU
charindex(',', substring(@SearchExpression, (charindex(',', @SearchExpression) + 4), len(@SearchExpression))) - 1 
--This second line determines how far to substring past the ,=OU by searching for everyting past the first comma then looking for the second comma
 ) as Answer
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a fun one

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(value, 4, LEN(value)-4) FROM STRING_SPLIT(string, ',') WHERE SUBSTRING(value, 1, 3)='OU='
```

Reference:
    https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-split-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

Answer (score 0):

```
declare @t table (String varchar(500))

insert into @t values('CN=username,OU=Tex,OU=Users,OU=Region1,DC=company,DC=com')

select SUBSTRING(String,charindex('tex',String),len('tex')) from @t
```